# C++ std::vector issue (imgui)

Tags: c++, imgui

I've had this issue for a while now and I'm not sure exactly how to fix it.

Here's the issue:

```cpp
std::vector<const char*> arr = {};
static char input[48] = "";
ImGui::InputTextWithHint("##Input", "Put your input here", input, IM_ARRAYSIZE(input));

if (ImGui::Button("add to array")){
arr.pushback(input);
}
```

When I press add, it adds the input into the vector, but if I press add again and change the text, it changes all pushed items of the vector to the input text. Can anyone help?

Comment: This one [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `std::vector<const char*>` -- Why not simply `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Doing as @PaulMcKenzie said would solve the problem

Comment: ill try string :/

Comment: its static and your vector is `char*`, so every element is pointing to the exact same memory. You'll have to use heap allocation to maintain its life time or use `std::string` (which does this anyway)

Answer (score -1):

You are pushing the same pointer to the array each time. You would have to allocate a new string with the buffer's contents after pressing the button.

```
if (ImGui::Button("add to array")){
  char* inputS = (char*)malloc((strlen(input) + 1) * sizeof(*input));  // allocate a separate string
  strcpy(inputS, input);        // copy until the first \0 byte is reached 
  arr.pushback(inputS);
}
```

This is C-style, which some people might not want to see in modern C++. You can do the same thing by declaring your array as `std::vector<std::string>`, which would make it so that when you push a new element to the vector, the constructor of `std::string` that takes `const char*` will be called (which is somewhat similar to the C-version).

So just

```
std::vector<std::string> arr;

if (ImGui::Button("add to array")){
  arr.pushback(input); // const char* input will be copied to the new std::string element of the array
}
```

ImGUI is a C-API, which means it doesn't understand `std::string`. To use `std::string` with ImGUI, you can use it's `.data()` (or `.c_str()`) method to access it's `const char*` data pointer.

Comment: That malloc is pretty unsafe

Comment: Why not just use `std::string`? There's almost no reason to use `malloc` or `strncpy` in c++.

Comment: @Timo So that the person asking the question understands what the problem is.

Comment: @dmitryguzeev But then you're introducing another issue, and that is dynamic allocation and having to manage the heap.  You're jumping from the frying pan into the fire.

Comment: Proposing a better solution doesn't prevent you from explaining what the problem is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wouldn't the copy constructor of the string also use dynamic allocation for data storage? This is just the same thing with less syntax sugar.

Comment: @dmitryguzeev -- Who is responsible for the memory cleanup?   The `std::string` class manages the entire memory -- there is no need for the programmer to get their hands dirty or make mistakes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Obviously you have all pointers in the resulting array. You can iterate and free afterwards

Comment: But why would you do that if you can just do nothing at all instead? With that reasoning you can also say why using `std::vector` if you can use a plain old array? And by extension: why use C++ when you can use C?

Comment: @dmitryguzeev -- *You can iterate and free afterwards* -- And if you forget to do that?  Or if you do that too many times?  Why tempt fate -- just use `std::string`.

Comment: using std::string produces simpler code with equivalent functionality which is safer from the point of memory management

Comment: Obviously that's the case. But, either way, it is useful for a beginner to know C memory management to not have these issues writing C++ code. Updated the answer to contain the C++ RAII version.

Comment: By the way, it is not the copy constructor that will be called with std::vector<std::string>.

Comment: @Doch88 what is it then?

Comment: @dmitryguzeev a simple constructor that takes const char* as argument

Comment: @dmitryguzeev the copy constructor takes a std::string instead.

Comment: @Doch88 Yeah makes sense, I don't really use classes in C++ :)

Comment: i tried to use std::vector<std::string> and the imgui list box. It won't accept a string , even if you try to convert it.

Comment: @xo1337 What does the compiler say?

Comment: it says: ```no instance of overloaded function "ImGui::ListBox" matches the arguments```

Comment: @xo1337 imgui is a C-API, so you would have to pass `const char*` to it. Use `str.data()` in the argument list

Comment: but someone said to use a std::string to solve my problem. And it didn't fix it lol

Comment: @xo1337 -- Any string class would have a way to return a `const char *`, otherwise it would be practically useless.  That's what the `c_str()` and `data()` functions provide.

Comment: @xo1337 well there was no ListBox call in your code example

Comment: i forgot to add the list box, one sec lol

Comment: @xo1337 -- Hopefully you are understanding why `std::string` was recommended, and not simply copying and pasting answers into your code without this knowledge.  The issue is that the third-party function you are trying to call wants a `const char *`.  Well ok, that is provided by the `c_str()` method of the `std::string` class.

Comment: Your C code with `strncpy` is wrong, you need to malloc one byte more for the string terminator. You also don't need `strncpy`, you can simply use `strcpy` because you know that the destination buffer is bug enough. But anyway using `std::string` is the way to go, this is C++, not C.

Comment: i changed my std::vector type to a std::string and for my listbox, i tried doing:
ImGui::ListBox("##box", &currentIndex, arr.data()->c_str());, and that didn't work.

Comment: _and that didn't work_: what didn't work? Did it not compile? Did it not run? Where there any error messages?

Comment: @xo1337 `arr.data()->c_str())` --> `arr.data()` *or* `arr.c_str()`.  You're not supposed to stick one on the other.  Are you aware of what member functions are, or how to [interpret the documentation for these functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)?